# SDL2 Blit Scaled from a palettized (8bpp) Surface gives error: Blit combination not supported

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I'm using 8bpp surfaces for a NES emulator so it's convenient to do simple palette swaps instead of having to fiddle with the pixel data.
But Blitting Scaled from an 8bpp Surface gives the error `Blit combination not supported` regardless if the destination is 8bpp or 32bpp.
Any suggestion to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course the solution was Blitting from 8bpp to 32bpp and then doing BlitScaled between 32bpp surfaces.